# progressbar.js как заставить анимацию происходить при скролле к месту блока?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Доброго времени суток, столкнулся с проблемой: у меня есть несколько круглых прогрессбаров, над ними есть хедер. Мне нужно чтобы анимация прогрессбаров происходила когда пользователь проскроллит страницу к нужному месту. Я использую библиотеку [progressbar.js](https://kimmobrunfeldt.github.io/progressbar.js/), пробовал сдеделать через [wow.js](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/), но ничего не получаетс, так как анимация додаеться в js коде.
 Песочница: [**пример**](https://jsfiddle.net/psb5rnpm/6/)

```
        var circle__wordpress = new ProgressBar.Circle('#skills--wordpress', {
        color: '#FFEA82',
        trailColor: '#eee',
        trailWidth: 1,
        duration: 1700,
        easing: 'easeInOut',
        strokeWidth: 2,
        from: {color: '#FFEA82', a:0.5},
        to: {color: '#769338', a:1},
        // Set default step function for all animate calls
        step: function(state, circle) {
            circle.path.setAttribute('stroke', state.color);
        }
    });

    circle__wordpress.animate(0.65);
};
```

атк выглядит инициализация прогрессбара.

Анимацию загрузки прогрессбара вы не увидите, так как она произойдет еще до того как вы прокрутите до прогрессбара, все что мне нужно : чтобы анимция происходила в тот момент - когда человек прокртутит к прогрессбару.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zdusnvLq/1/ работает ли у вас функция по получению координат элемента bar? вставьте себе в код и замените на ваш элемент : circle__wordpress

Comment: @Horchynskyi, не работает, может есть еще варианты?

Comment: я просто не разбираюсь в progressbar.js. Ну у меня вариант это найти координаты элемента который создается и при достижении его кординат делать анимацию. Эти элементы же должны добавляться на страницу и иметь координаты?

Comment: может ему можно какой id назначить или класс?

Comment: просто в вашем варианте оно сразу запускает анимацию без никакого условия. ну я не знаю условие только одно может быть - если скролл окна не меньше чем координата top элемента + там ещё проверка на размер экрана пользователя (в функции она есть)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/psb5rnpm/15/ а так?

Comment: @Horchynskyi, не работает :( ладно, спасибо большое за усердствия, уберу эти прогрессбары, библиотека еще не до конца доработанна, буду искать другой путь.

Comment: покажите код как вы эту функцию применяете

Comment: @Horchynskyi добавил

Comment: а что на alert виводит?

Comment: @Horchynskyi добавил, кстати, я тоже зі Львову :D

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63392/discussion-between-horchynskyi-and--).